# Rails email to german emailaddress with ä ö ü doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

i'm using ActionMailer to send emails via Rails. Now i tested to send a mail to a email-address which contains ä, ö or ü in the email-address like test@täst.de. When Rails tries to send the mail it encodes the address to UTF-8 and looks like this:

```
To: =?UTF-8?B?IGtvbnRha3RAZGllLWLDvGNocy5kZQ==?=
```

But this doesn't work. 
Did somebody know, what I need to change, that I can send mails to german email-addresses?

Thanks.

Comment: tried to add # encoding: utf-8 at the top of file ?

Comment: and also try to include charset, "default :from => "mikel@example.org", :charset => 'Shift_JIS'"

Comment: i'm already using # encoding: utf-8 at the top of the file, but i will test to setup the charset for the mail

Comment: i tested the :charset => "Shift_JIS" and the mail to: looks like this: To: =?SHIFT-JIS?B?IGtvbnRha3RAZGllLWLDvGNocy5kZQ==?=